# regarding cross checking of files in an directory

Tags: java, io

I have developed a java program that copies the file from source folder to destination folder
there are 10 serialized files that it copies from source folder to destination folder

but one thing is missing in it is that let say if the files are already exists in the destination folder then in that case it should not copy
so basically a look is done within in one second that will check the destination folder contain those 10 serialized files or not
if not then in that case only it should copy and after copying it should again check within in second whether file exists or not , Please advise how to achieve this

```
//Create a class extends with TimerTask
class ScheduledTask extends TimerTask {

    public void run() {
        InputStream inStream = null;
        OutputStream outStream = null;

        try {
            File source = new File("C:\\cache\\");
            File target = new File("C:\\Authclient\\cache\\");

            // Already exists. do not copy
            /*if (target.exists()) { 
                return;
            }*/

            File[] files = source.listFiles();
            for (File file : files) {
                inStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(target + "/" + file.getName());

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                // copy the file content in bytes
                while ((length = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                inStream.close();
                outStream.close();
            }
            System.out.println("File is copied successful!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class Copycache {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException  {
        Timer time = new Timer();
        ScheduledTask task = new ScheduledTask();
        time.schedule(task, new Date(), TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1));
    }

}
```

the above exists implementation which is commented is not working correct rite now please advise

Comment: Why do you want to check again AFTER copying if the file is there? If the copying fails then you will get an exception, there's no need to check this again.

Answer (score 0):

I am curious about your exact requirements. Consider this small example:

```
File file = new File("test.txt");
if (!file.exists())
{
    FileOutputStream fis = new FileOutputStream(file);
    fis.write("blabla".getBytes());
    fis.close();
}
```

Now put a breakpoint on the line FileOutputStream fis...
Run it and wait at the breakpoint, then create the test.txt manually and put some data in it.
Then continue running the program.

Your program will overwrite the contents of test.txt without warning.

If timing is so crucial here you will need to figure out a different solution.

Edit: I got curious and did some more testing. It seems it won't even throw an exception if you add the line `file.createNewFile();`, break there, create the file and then continue the application. I wonder why..